# Surface swept by a moving line generating constant negative Gauss curvature $K$ and $ \kappa_g$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

One end of a flexible curved line in $\mathbb R^3$ moves on the y-axis sweeping out a constant negative Gauss curvature $K$ surface with constant geodesic curvature $\kappa_g$.

Please help find its parametrization (up to its y- axis rotation  as these two scalars are isometric first fundamental form dependent).

Is it possible to find when $K>0$ also ? Intuitively it appears not so to me, but a proper proof may be required.